# How do you return from a function early in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, return

Common Lisp has `return-from`; is there any sort of `return` in Clojure for when you want to return early from a function?

Comment: Clojure code tends not to be structured as a series of statements, so returning early is not necessarily as meaningful. If you'd like to give an example of where you're wanting it, people might be able to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There isn't any explicit return statement in clojure. You could hack something together using a catch/throw combination if you want to, but since clojure is much more functional than common lisp, the chances you actually *need* an early return right in the middle of some nested block is much smaller than in CL. The only 'good' reason I can see for return statements is when you're dealing with mutable objects in a way that's not idiomatic in clojure.

I wouldn't go as far as saying that it's never useful, but I think in Clojure, if your algorithm needs a return statement, it's a major code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As a concrete example: When parsing command line args, I wanted to check whether each option was valid. At first, I tried checking each option, if one option was invalid, then I wanted to return a useful message to user before continuing on with validating the rest of the options. After realizing return in middle of function is a code smell, I wrote a "validate" function that returns a list of messages (one message for each invalid option value). If the list of messages returned by validate is empty, then all options validated successfully. Much nicer after the refactor!

Answer (score 64):

When you need to bail out of a computation early, you need a way to do that, not an argument from purists. Usually you need it when you're reducing a big collection and a certain value indicates that there's no point in further processing the collection. To that end, the ever-practical Clojure provides the [`reduced`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced) function.

A simple example to illustrate is that when multiplying a sequence of numbers, if you encounter a zero, you already know that the final result will be zero, so you don't need to look at the rest of the sequence. Here's how you code that with `reduced`:

```
(defn product [nums]
  (reduce #(if (zero? %2)
               (reduced 0.0)
               (* %1 %2))
          1.0
          nums))
```

`reduced` wraps the value you give it in a sentinel data structure so that `reduce` knows to stop reading from the collection and simply return the `reduced` value right now. Hey, it's pure-functional, even!

You can see what's going on if you wrap the above `if` in a `do` with a `(println %1 %2)`:

```
user=> (product [21.0 22.0 0.0 23.0 24.0 25.0 26.0])
1.0 21.0
21.0 22.0
462.0 0.0
0.0

user=> (product [21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0 25.0 26.0])
1.0 21.0
21.0 22.0
462.0 23.0
10626.0 24.0
255024.0 25.0
6375600.0 26.0
1.657656E8
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. "When you need to bail out of a computation early, you need a way to do that, not an argument from purists". Efficiency is always a must. Period. Example of a function to check if an id is duplicated in a set of maps: (defn duplicated? [id myset] (reduce (fn [a v] (if (= (:id v) id) (reduced true) false)) false myset))

Answer (score 17):

Unless you're writing some really funky code, the only reason you'd ever want to return early is if some condition is met. But since functions always return the result of the last form evaluated, `if` is already this function — just put the value that you want to return in the body of the `if` and it will return that value if the condition is met.

Answer (score 15):

I'm no expert in Clojure, but it seems it does not have those construct to try to be more functional. Take a look at what Stuart Halloway says [here](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2008/09/16/pcl-clojure-chapter-5.html):

> Common Lisp also supports a return-from macro to "return" from the
>   middle of a function. This encourages an imperative style of
>   programming, which Clojure discourages.
>
> However, you can solve the same problems in a different way. Here is
>   the return-from example, rewritten in a functional style so that no
>   return-from is needed:

```
(defn pair-with-product-greater-than [n]
 (take 1 (for [i (range 10) j (range 10) :when (> (* i j) n)] [i j])))
```

That is, use lazy sequences and returning values based on conditions.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use [cond](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond) . And if on some conditions you would need to evaluate multiple expressions use [do](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/do).
Here is an example:

```clj
(defn fact [x]
  (cond
    (< x 0) (do (println (str x " is negative number"))
                (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "x should be 0 or higher")))
    (<= x 1) 1
    :else (* x (fact (- x 1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` option already given is probably the best choice, and note since maps are easy, you can always return `{:error "blah"}` in the error condition, and`{result: x}` in the valid condition.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a return statement in Clojure.  Even if you choose not to execute some code using a flow construct such as `if` or `when`, the function will always return something, in these cases `nil`.  The only way out is to throw an exception, but even then it will either bubble all the way up and kill your thread, or be caught by a function - which will return a value.

Answer (score -2):

In short, no.  If this is a real problem for you then you can get around it with
"[the maybe monad](https://clojure.github.io/algo.monads/#clojure.algo.monads/maybe-m)" Monads have a *high intellectual overhead* so for many cases clojurians tend to avoid the "if failed return" style of programming.

It helps to break the function up into smaller functions to reduce the friction from this.