# Better way of writing multiple if checks in a Clojure function?

Tags: if-statement, clojure, idioms

I have a Clojure function that looks something like the following.

```
(defn calculate-stuff [data]
  (if (some-simple-validation data)
    (create-error data)
    (let [foo (calculate-stuff-using data)]
      (if (failed? foo)
        (create-error foo)
        (let [bar (calculate-more-stuff-using foo)]
          (if (failed? bar)
            (create-error bar)
            (calculate-response bar)))))))
```

Which works fine but is a little hard to read, so I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic Clojure way of writing this?

I thought about making `some-simple-validation`, `calculate-stuff-using` and `calculate-more-stuff-using` throw exceptions and using a try/catch block but that felt like using exceptions for control flow which didn't feel correct.

I can't let the exceptions escape this function either as I'm using it to map a seq of maps and I still want to continue processing the remainder.

I guess what I'm after is something like this?

```
(defn calculate-stuff [data]
  (let-with-checking-function
    [valid-data (some-simple-validation data)
     foo (calculate-stuff-using valid-data)
     bar (calculate-more-stuff-using foo)]
    failed?)                    ; this function is used to check each variable
      (create-error %)          ; % is the variable that failed
      (calculate-response bar)) ; all variables are OK
```

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7491360.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a failed validation indicates an error condition, an exception (and a try-catch block) may be the best way of handling it. Especially if it is not a "normal" occurrance (i.e. invalid cust-id, etc).

For more "normal" but still "invalid" cases, you might use `some->` (pronounced "some-thread") to quietly squelch "bad" cases.  Just have your validators return `nil` for bad data, and `some->` will abort the processing chain:

```
(defn proc-num [n]
  (when (number? n)
    (println :proc-num n)
    n))

(defn proc-int [n]
  (when (int? n)
    (println :proc-int n)
    n))

(defn proc-odd [n]
  (when (odd? n)
    (println :proc-odd n)
    n))

(defn proc-ten [n]
  (when (< 10 n)
    (println :proc-10 n)
    n))

(defn process [arg]
  (when (nil? arg)
    (throw (ex-info "Cannot have nil data" {:arg arg})))
  (some-> arg
    proc-num
    proc-int
    proc-odd
    proc-ten))
```

results:

```
(process :a) => nil

(process "foo") => nil

:proc-num 12
:proc-int 12
(process 12) => nil

:proc-num 13
:proc-int 13
:proc-odd 13
:proc-10 13
(process 13) => 13

(throws? (process nil)) => true
```

Having said this, you are now using `nil` to mean "data validation failure", so you cannot have `nil` in your data.

---

## Using Exceptions For Invalid Data

Using `nil` as a special value to short-circuit processing can work, but it might be easier to use plain-old exceptions, especially for cases that are clearly "bad data":

```
(defn parse-with-default [str-val default-val]
  (try
    (Long/parseLong str-val)
    (catch Exception e
      default-val))) ; default value

(parse-with-default "66-Six" 42) => 42
```

I have [a little macro to automate this process](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#default-value-in-case-of-exception) called `with-exception-default`:

```
(defn proc-num [n]
  (when-not (number? n)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Not a number")))
  n)

(defn proc-int [n]
  (when-not (int? n)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Not int")))
  n)

(defn proc-odd [n]
  (when-not (odd? n)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Not odd")))
  n)

(defn proc-ten [n]
  (when-not (< 10 n)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Not big enough")))
  n)

(defn process [arg]
  (with-exception-default 42  ; <= default value to return if anything fails
    (-> arg
      proc-num
      proc-int
      proc-odd
      proc-ten)))

(process nil)    => 42
(process :a)     => 42
(process "foo")  => 42
(process 12)     => 42

(process 13)     => 13
```

This avoids giving a special meaning to `nil` or any other "sentinal" value, and uses `Exception` for its normal purpose of altering control flow in the presence of errors.

Comment: This is what I've started doing in many cases. It ends up working a lot like Haskell's Maybe chaining. Once it fails somewhere along the chain, the whole thing fails and returns nil.

Comment: I went with using exceptions in the end, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Fantastic answer - clear and direct. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

That's a usual issue on Clojure code bases. One approach is to wrap your data into something that provides more information, namely if the operation succeeded. There are a couple of libraries that help you with that.

For example with cats (http://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/):

```
(m/mlet [a (maybe/just 1)
         b (maybe/just (inc a))]
  (m/return (* a b)))
```

Or with results - I helped on this one (https://github.com/clanhr/result):

```
(result/enforce-let [r1 notgood
                     r2 foo])
    (println "notgoof will be returned"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. My solution was to copy the some->> macro and adjust it a little bit:

```
(defmacro run-until->> [stop? expr & forms]
     (let [g (gensym)
           steps (map (fn [step] `(if (~stop? ~g) ~g (->> ~g ~step)))
               forms)]
        `(let [~g ~expr
               ~@(interleave (repeat g) (butlast steps))]
             ~(if (empty? steps)
                g
                (last steps)))))
```

instead of checking for nils, this macro will check for your predefined condition. For example:

```
(defn validate-data [[status data]]
    (if (< (:a data) 10)
       [:validated data]
       [:failed data]))

(defn calculate-1 [[status data]]
     [:calculate-1 (assoc data :b 2)])

(defn calculate-2 [[status data]]
    (if (:b data)
       [:calculate-2 (update data :b inc)]
       [:failed data]))

(deftest test
    (let [initial-data [:init {:a 1}]]
       (is (= [:calculate-2 {:a 1, :b 3}] 
              (run-until->> #(= :failed (first %))
                            initial-data
                            (validate-data)
                            (calculate-1)
                            (calculate-2))))

       (is (= [:failed {:a 1}] 
              (run-until->> #(= :failed (first %))
                            initial-data
                            (validate-data)
                            (calculate-2))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

One of examples from other answers uses `some->` macro that has a flaw: every failure should print a message into console and return `nil`. That is not good because a `nil` value also may indicate good results, especially for empty collections. Needless to say that you also need not only to print an error, but to handle it somehow or log it somewhere.

The easiest way to refactor your code would be just to decompose it. Say, you may put everything from the negative branch of the first `if` into a separate function, and that's it. Those two functions will become easier to test and debug.

As for me, it would be the best choice because it will solve the problem immediately.

A case with exceptions is also good. Do not invent your own Exception classes, just throw a map using `ex-info`. Once caught, such an exception returns all the data thrown with it:

```
(if (some-checks data)
  (some-positive-code data)
  (throw (ex-into "Some useful message" {:type :error 
                                         :data data})))
```

to catch it:

```
(try
  (some-validation data)
(catch Exception e
  (let [err-data (ex-data e)]
    ; ...)))
```

Finally, there might be a case to use monads, but be aware of overengineering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created [Promenade](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/promenade) to handle exactly this kind of scenarios.