# Clojure: Bailing out of a function

Tags: clojure

I am writing a simple test-data generation system for Clojure, which generates a control-flow graph for a given function and performs an evolutionary search for input data. The fitness function driving this evolutionary search is a version of the target function with labels at each branch of every conditional form (e.g. `(if TEST (do (branch-label ...) THEN) (do (branch-label ...) ELSE`). The `branch-label` function is called with the index of the node in the control-flow graph which corresponds to the current point in the execution of the function and the branch distance for the other branch. The function then calculates a fitness value based on approach level and branch distance and stores it in an atom. For the purposes of speeding up the process, I want the fitness function to immediately terminate should the execution follow a path which would render reaching the goal impossible, or if the goal is reached.

My initial approach was to make the `branch-label` function throw a specific type of exception which would then be caught by my search function, but then it occurred to me that it would be possible for the fitness function itself to catch the exception prematurely, if the terminating condition was met inside a try-catch block for instance.

e.g. Suppose we have this in a function:

```
(try (if TEST THEN ELSE) (catch Exception _))
```

The fitness function would be something like:

```
(try 
    (if TEST 
      (do (branch-label ...) THEN)
      (do (branch-label ...) ELSE))
    (catch Exception _))
```

So if `branch-label` where to throw any kind of exception it would be swallowed up here and the function may continue running.

My other idea was to run the fitness function on a separate thread and call `(.stop (Thread/currentThread))` from inside the branch label function, but it seems that all sources say that Thread.stop should never ever be used.

So to sum up, my problem is that of trying to find a (relatively) clean way of immediately bailing out of a running function, outside of Clojure's usual control-flow mechanics.

Comment: Return a value indicating the condition? Can you add the relevant code from `branch-label`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7491360

Comment: @Lee The return value from `branch-label` is inaccessible since it is called in a do block before the branch itself so it dosen't affect anything. The jist of the code is: calculate fitness and store it in fitness atom, check if a stopping condition been met (i.e. critical branch or goal met) and if so, bail out.

Comment: Can you update the caller to assign it in a `let`/`if-let` block and branch on it? It would be clearer if you could add the code to your question.

Comment: It is not clear to me why throwing an exception would not work. If you make the exception specific enough, e.g. by choosing specific type or a specific value (in case you use ex-info), what stops you from catching it where you want to catch it? I think you should provide a small code example in your question that illustrates why you think throwing an exception will not work.

Comment: @Rulle If we want to generate test data for functions which feature try-catch blocks then there's a possibility that any exception `branch-label` may though would be swallowed up prematurely. I've added an example to my question to illustrate.

Comment: great question!

Comment: It's been a long time since I've fiddled with the JVM this way, so this isn't an answer, but I would suggest looking at the debug/instrumentation interfaces offered by the JVM. What you basically want to do is manage the execution of your fitness function using the equivalent of breakpoints, and terminate execution under conditions determined out-of-band to the function itself. That's what a debugger does. This sort of approach should also mean that you don't have to rewrite the function to use it for fitness, which can be very messy to get right. Sounds like a fun project, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've arrived at what I feel is a satisfactory solution. Instead of using `Thread.stop`, I run the fitness function as a future, and pass it a promise (which in turn gets passed to `branch-label`). The main thread then derefs this promise (and is thus blocked). Upon reaching a stopping condition, the final fitness is delivered to the promise and the main thread gets unblocked, and proceeds to cancel the future.